# У кого есть материал как работать с FaceDetection Camera2API?

Tags: java, android, камера

На официальных источниках я вообще не нашел информации... Как работать с Camera API есть много примеров, но насчет Camera2API вообще ничего..., пара обсуждений на стаке и все... есть один похожий вопрос на мой, но у меня проблема не решилась...

**[Вот ссылка](http://goo.gl/pnJvVH) на такой же вопрос...**

**Я взял пример гугла по Camera2API**

Google: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic.

Вот что я сделал, но у меня не определяет лица...

Я добавил мод

```
private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
    try {
        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;

        // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

        // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
        mPreviewRequestBuilder
                = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        // The camera is already closed
                        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                            return;
                        }

                        // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                        mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        try {



//           ---->>         Установка модуля распознания лица
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE,
                                    CameraMetadata.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_FULL);



                            // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

                            // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
                            setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);

                            // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                            mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();

                            mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                                    mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(
                            @NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        System.out.println("Failed строка 757");
                    }
                }, null
        );
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback
        = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onCaptureProgressed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                    @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                    @NonNull CaptureResult partialResult) {
        process(partialResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                   @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                   @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
        process(result);
    }

    private void process(CaptureResult result) {


--->   //здесь проверяю получает ли он массив лиц или нет + непонятный мод
        Integer mode = result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE);
        Face[] faces = result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACES);
        if(faces != null && mode != null)
            System.out.println("tagDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD" + "faces : " +
                    faces.length + " , mode : " + mode);

        switch (mState) {
            case STATE_PREVIEW: {
                // We have nothing to do when the camera preview is working normally.

//                  Установка модуля распознания лица
                mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE,
                        CameraMetadata.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_FULL);
                break;
            }
```

**потом проверил максимальное кол-во лиц которое может принимать камера и какой то мод(до сих пор не пойму что он означает)**

```
private void setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height) {

    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                    = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

            // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
            //проверяет какая камера активна сейчас, если внутренняя то цикл запускается заново
            Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
            if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                continue;
            }

            max_count = characteristics.get(
                    CameraCharacteristics.STATISTICS_INFO_MAX_FACE_COUNT);
            modes = characteristics.get(
                    CameraCharacteristics.STATISTICS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FACE_DETECT_MODES);

            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! max_count " + max_count + " modes " + modes);
```

**Выводит такое :**

```
I/System.out: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! max_count 16 modes [I@3e2907e8
```

**и вот что в лог печатает**

```
03-08 18:34:07.018 7405-7438/com.example.android.camera2basic I/System.out: tagDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDfaces : 0 , mode : 1
03-08 18:34:07.048 7405-7438/com.example.android.camera2basic I/System.out: tagDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDfaces : 0 , mode : 1
03-08 18:34:07.078 7405-7438/com.example.android.camera2basic I/System.out: tagDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDfaces : 0 , mode : 1
03-08 18:34:07.118 7405-7438/com.example.android.camera2basic I/System.out: tagDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDfaces : 0 , mode : 1
03-08 18:34:07.148 7405-7438/com.example.android.camera2basic I/System.out: tagDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDfaces : 0 , mode : 1
03-08 18:34:07.178 7405-7438/com.example.android.camera2basic I/System.out: tagDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDfaces : 0 , mode : 1
03-08 18:34:07.218 7405-7438/com.example.android.camera2basic I/System.out: tagDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDfaces : 0 , mode : 1
03-08 18:34:07.258 7405-7438/com.example.android.camera2basic I/System.out: tagDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDfaces : 0 , mode : 1
03-08 18:34:07.288 7405-7438/com.example.android.camera2basic I/System.out: tagDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDfaces : 0 , mode : 1
03-08 18:34:07.308 7405-7438/com.example.android.camera2basic I/System.out: tagDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDfaces : 0 , mode : 1
03-08 18:34:07.348 7405-7438/com.example.android.camera2basic I/System.out: tagDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDfaces : 0 , mode : 1
```

Как сделать так чтоб все работало правильно? Даже не знаю где почитать...
Буду рад любому совету)) а еще лучше если дадите ссылку на рабочий пример для наглядности... чтоб посмотреть как это работает на практике... А то неделю уже не могу разобраться((

Comment: Могу предложить вам ознакомиться с библиотекой OpenCV. Есть там даже пример такой https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/face-detection. Да и в книжке по этому инструменту есть примеры с картинками, где как раз происходит распознание лиц. Документация http://opencv.org/platforms/android/opencv4android-samples.html. Про android-API я вам ничего подсказать не смогу, но в целом, это очень серьёзный инструмент, который активно развивается и поддерживается. Да и примеров там достаточно много.